# Calculate row sums by variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

what's the easiest way to calculate row-wise sums? For example if I wanted to calculate the sum of all variables with "txt_"? (see example below)

```r
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 txt_1 = c(1, 1, 0),
                 txt_2 = c(1, 0, 0),
                 txt_3 = c(1, 0, 0))
```

Comment: what result are you expecting? One sum or sum for each appropriate column?

Comment: sum = c(3, 1, 0)

Comment: It's not tidyverse, but `rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "txt")])` would do it. See previous questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482532/sum-cells-of-certain-columns-for-each-row and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237034/sum-up-certain-variables-columns-by-variable-names and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515925/rowsums-conditional-on-column-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**base R**

We can first use `grepl` to find the column names that start with `txt_`, then use `rowSums` on the subset.

```
rowSums(df[, grepl("txt_", names(df))])

[1] 3 1 0
```

If you want to bind it back to the original dataframe, then we can bind the output to the original dataframe.

```
cbind(df, sums = rowSums(df[, grepl("txt_", names(df))]))

  var1 txt_1 txt_2 txt_3 sums
1    1     1     1     1    3
2    2     1     0     0    1
3    3     0     0     0    0
```

**Tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("txt_"))))

  var1 txt_1 txt_2 txt_3 sum
1    1     1     1     1   3
2    2     1     0     0   1
3    3     0     0     0   0
```

Or if you want just the vector, then we can use `pull`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("txt_")))) %>% 
  pull(sum)

[1] 3 1 0
```

**Data Table**

Here is a `data.table` option as well:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[ ,sum := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = grep("txt_", names(dt))]

dt[["sum"]]
# [1] 3 1 0
```

Comment: Not bad, but I need to call the columns by name as the real data frame is much bigger than the example data

Comment: @D.Studer Oh okay, I understand now. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another dplyr option:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(starts_with("txt"))))
```